# Como criar um input que não aceite números, apenas letras?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou criando um código que faça com que o usuário informe apenas o seu nome, sem inserir nenhum número. Mas após testar várias vezes, percebo que o código comete algumas falhas e aceita alguns nomes com números inseridos, porém não estou encontrando o meu erro.

```
while True:
    try:
        numeros = [x for x in range(0, 10)]
        nome = input('digite seu nome: ')
        for n in numeros:
            while str(n) in nome:
                print('seu nome deve conter apenas letras')
                nome = input('digite seu nome novamente (sem números): ')
                continue
        else:
            break
    finally:
        print(f'seu nome {nome}, foi registrado com sucesso')
```

Eu faço testes inserindo o nome "maria" com variados formatos, exemplo: "maria123", "62maria", "maria10" e coincidentemente toda vez que digito "maria49" e em seguida digito "1maria", o código aceita o "1maria" e finaliza.

Answer (score -2):

Para esse tipo de problema seria melhor eliminar um `for` utilizando [Expressões Regulares](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.8/howto/regex.html) já que trata-se de uma filtragem da string recebida pelo `input`.

Para utilizar expressões regulares no Python você pode utilizar o método `find_all()` da biblioteca `re`.

Uma ótima ferramenta para praticar RegEx antes de colocar no código (além de prover uma série de referências de como utilizar as expressões regulares) é o [RegExr](https://regexr.com/).

Após filtrar por números, basta validar se há números e o que você quer devolver para o usuários com base na existência (ou na não existência) desses números.

Mais sobre o `re`: https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/re.html

Mais especificamente sobre o `find_all`: https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/re.html#re.findall